# Return value after promise or since inside promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I'm trying to get a value result after the promise end. But if I put a return result at the end of a function, it always returns true. While inside the promise at the end, the value changes to false.
How I do that?

Here is an example of my code:

```
function validations(){
    result = true;

    getDistance().then(function(response) {
        var distance = (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text).split(" ")[0];

        if(distance>=100)
            result = false;
        return result;
    }

 }
```

In this case my functions is "undefined" when I need a true/false value.
When I put a return result at the end, it always returns true.

```
function validations(){
result = true;

    getDistance().then(function(response) {
        var distance = (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text).split(" ")[0];

       if(distance>=100)
        result = false;
    }
  return result
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. You could use the Promise pattern:

```
function validations() {
    return getDistance().then(function(response) {
        var distance = (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text).split(" ")[0];
        return distance>=100;
    });
}

validations().then(function(trueOrFalse){
    //  trueOrFalse is true if distance was less than or equal to 100
});
```

or a callback pattern:

```
function validations(cb) {
    getDistance().then(function(response) {
        var distance = (response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text).split(" ")[0];
        cb(null, distance>=100);
    }, cb);
}

validations(function(error, trueOrFalse){
    //  trueOrFalse is true if distance was less than or equal to 100  
});
```

In either case, the important thing to note is that you are not trying to execute code that depends on a value, until that value is set.

Comment: at the first option using promise pattern, the function return me: Object {} with this: always: ()
done: ()
fail: ()
pipe: ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress: ()
promise: ( obj )
state: ()
then: ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
__proto__: Object

Comment: that means the return value is a Promise. The method you need to call to get your `trueOfFalse` value is `.then()`